# ORDER BY in appengine DataViewer using GQL doesnt work for one column

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

I have a question which presumably has a simple solution, but I cannot find any documentation to solve the following problem.

I have a DB with a few columns, such as firstname, modified, and version. I can order by firstname or modified easily, using the DataViewer in appengine:

```
SELECT * FROM DBUser ORDER BY modified
```

which works perfectly fine. It gives me my DB ordered.

Now, if I want to order by column "version", it doesn't work.

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM DBUser ORDER BY version
SELECT * FROM DBUser ORDER BY _version
```

but they don't work. I get this message:

```
No results in Empty namespace.
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "version" column must be indexed.